# MVC 4 Windows Authentication all pages ask for credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, intranet

I have a mvc 4 intranet application.

All pages ask for credentials, when i provide these the application tries to redirect to a login.aspx page

Please assist, this web application needs to login automatically based on Active Directory.

Been battling with this for 3 days now

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you are using windows authentication the page should not redirect to login page. It shows error message.

In web.config file modification:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment the following lines

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

In visual studio select project name and click F4 then enable the following.

```
Windows Authentication
Anonymous Authentication
```

Place authorization filter globally or controller level.

Run the application.